# NHibernate Projections Duplicates To List

Tags: .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a problem with nHibernate projections. I don't even know if what I'm attempting can be done but if any nHibernate experts can help me I'd be grateful.

I'm using nHibernate criteria to query a database and I'm returning the result projected to a different (slimmed down) object.

I get a list of returns like

```
Id    CompanyId  Description  
1        1          Desc1  
1        2          Desc1  
1        3          Desc1  
2        1          Desc2  
2        3          Desc2  
3        1          Desc3  
3        2          Desc3  
3        3          Desc3
```

when I use this object

```
int Id  
int CompanyId  
string Description
```

What I'm looking for is to get something more like

```
Id CompanyId Description  
1  [1, 2, 3] Description  
2  [1, 3] Description  
3  [1, 2, 3] Description
```

From an object like this

```
int id  
List`<int`> companyId  
string description
```

The current code I have is similar to

```
 result = session.CreateCriteria<Object>()
           .Add(Restrictions.Eq("SiteId", 616))
           .SetProjection(Projections.Distinct(Projections.ProjectionList()
           .Add(Projections.Property("Id"), "Id")
           .Add(Projections.Property("CompanyId"), "CompanyId")
           .Add(Projections.Property("Description"), "Description")
           .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<ObjectReduced>()).List<ObjectReduced>();
```

So I'd like to know if there is anything here I can do to achieve this, or even if this is completely the wrong approach and there is something better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that directly in NHibernate. The best way to achieve this is to get the result set as you are currently doing and then populate the reduced object with the CompanyIds. Something like:

```
var temp = session.CreateCriteria<Object>()
           .Add(Restrictions.Eq("SiteId", 616))
           .SetProjection(Projections.Distinct(Projections.ProjectionList()
           .Add(Projections.Property("Id"), "Id")
           .Add(Projections.Property("CompanyId"), "CompanyId")
           .Add(Projections.Property("Description"), "Description")
           .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<ObjectReduced>())
           .List<ObjectReduced>();
var groups = temp.GroupBy(x => x.Id);
var result = new List<ObjectReduced>(groups.Count());
foreach (var member in groups)
{
    var first = member.First();
    var companyIds = member.Select(x => x.CompanyId);
    foreach (var companyId in companyIds)
    {
        first.CompanyIds.Add(companyId);
    }
    result.Add(first);
}
return result;
```

There's probably a LINQier way to do this but this is how I solved a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up getting back a list of Objects and then mapping to to ObjectReduced manually. I used your code to get the groups of Objects and added a few lines of code for the mapping.